# How do you set the tile entity data for a falling block in 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command:

`/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block", Properties:{}}}`

**(1.13)**

How do I add tile entity data to the command block i.e setting the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put any tile entity data into the `TileEntityData` tag, like so:

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},TileEntityData:{Command:"say hello"}}
```